# gvisGauge not displaying in R Shiny (empty space) - googleVis - Gauge

Tags: r, shiny, gauge, googlevis

I am trying to display a simple Gauge using the googleVis library in R Shiny.

However - the only thing that I can get to display is a blank space that matches with the width and height of the INVISIBLE gauge.
(I am having a similar image where I can't even get images to display using renderImage. So, the two fails may be connected.)

Any thoughts on how to fix the code below will be greatly appreciated:

From server.R:

```
output$gauge <- renderGvis({
M0 <- matrix(c('Label','Value'),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
M1 <- matrix(c('IRR',4),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
MU <- rbind(M0,M1)
df <- as.data.frame(MU)
gvisGauge(df,
options=list(min=0, max=10, greenFrom=8,
greenTo=10, yellowFrom=6, yellowTo=8,
redFrom=0, redTo=6, width=300, height=300));
})
```

From ui.R:

```
uiOutput("gauge")
```

Thanks,

Chad

Comment: `Your data.frame` is incorrectly specified.

Comment: Thank you, JD. Do you have an example of the proper way to set up the data.frame? Based on the documentation that I have found, I am supposed to stick a two-by-two matrix into "as.data.frame", with the top row being 'Label' and 'Value', and the second row being the actual label, and the actual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data.frame` was incorrectly specified

```
> M0 <- matrix(c('Label','Value'),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> M1 <- matrix(c('IRR',4),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> MU <- rbind(M0,M1)
> df <- as.data.frame(MU)
> df
     V1    V2
1 Label Value
2   IRR     4


library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 4, 1, 10),
    htmlOutput("view")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$view <- renderGvis({
     df <- data.frame(Label = "IRR", Value = input$n)
      gvisGauge(df,
                options=list(min=0, max=10, greenFrom=8,
                             greenTo=10, yellowFrom=6, yellowTo=8,
                             redFrom=0, redTo=6, width=300, height=300));

    })
  }
))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Also, one of the hang-ups was that I had been using uiOutput, instead of htmlOutput.